Difficulty in proving an inequality on norms
I am reading a paper in which the following inequality has been given which I am unable to see. Can someone give a proof of this?

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $a_i$ and $x_j$ be elements of $A$.
$\vert \vert \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m  a_ix_jx_j^* a_i^* \vert \vert^\frac{1}{2} \leq \vert \vert \sum_{i=1}^n  a_i a_i^* \vert \vert  ^\frac{1}{2} \vert \vert \sum_{j=1}^m  x_jx_j^*\vert \vert^\frac{1}{2} $


$$\begin{split}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ix_jx_j^\ast a_i^\ast &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(\sum_{j=1}^m x_jx_j^\ast)a_i^\ast\\
&\leq \|\sum_{j=1}^m x_jx_j^\ast\|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ia_i^\ast
\end{split}$$
Now take the norms of both sides and apply square roots.

Sorry.. how did you get less than equal to inequality in second line?

@MathLover Combine the following three facts: for $y \in A$, $y \leq |y|1$ (if $A$ is not unital, just adjoin a unit to make sense of this); if $y \leq y’$, then $aya^\ast \leq ay’a^\ast$; and if $y_1 \leq y’1, \cdots, y_n \leq y’n$, then $\sum{i=1}^n y_i \leq \sum{i=1}^n y’_i$.
